# Why a postgresql case statement's result does not work inside where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, where-clause, column-alias

I am solving a PostgreSQL problems in this [site](https://www.pgexercises.com/questions/joins/threejoin2.html).
My answer is:

```
select concat(mem.firstname, ' ', mem.surname), fac.name as facility,
case when mem.memid=0 then bks.slots*fac.guestcost
     else bks.slots*membercost
end  as cost
from cd.members mem
inner join cd.bookings bks on mem.memid=bks.memid
inner join cd.facilities fac on bks.facid=fac.facid

where bks.starttime >= '2012-09-14' and bks.starttime < '2012-09-15' and cost > 30
order by cost desc;
```

But it shows error `ERROR: column "cost" does not exist` for the `cost > 30` inside `WHERE` clause.
If the `cost` works inside `ORDER BY`, then why it is not working inside `WHERE`?

[image: The Problem description and database structure]

Answer (score 1):

This is correct.  You cannot use a column alias defined in the `SELECT` in the `WHERE`.  The simple solution is to use a lateral join to define the column alias:

```
select concat(mem.firstname, ' ', mem.surname), fac.name as facility,
       v.cost
from cd.members mem join
     cd.bookings bks
     on mem.memid = bks.memid join
     cd.facilities fac
     on bks.facid=fac.facid cross join
     (values (case when mem.memid = 0 then bks.slots * fac.guestcost
                   else bks.slots * membercost
              end)
     ) v(cost)
where bks.starttime >= '2012-09-14' and bks.starttime < '2012-09-15' and
      v.cost > 30
order by v.cost desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use any alias like this in where clause. Instead of t the alias I have used the condition as in select list:

```
select concat(mem.firstname, ' ', mem.surname), fac.name as facility,
case when mem.memid=0 then bks.slots*fac.guestcost
     else bks.slots*membercost
end  as cost
from cd.members mem
inner join cd.bookings bks on mem.memid=bks.memid
inner join cd.facilities fac on bks.facid=fac.facid

where bks.starttime >= '2012-09-14' and bks.starttime < '2012-09-15' and (case when mem.memid=0 then bks.slots*fac.guestcost
     else bks.slots*membercost
end  ) > 30
order by cost desc;
```